# When are questions on future releases appropriate?

Tags: discussion

This Q is one of the first:

[New Salesforce Layout Dreamforce 2012](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3506/new-salesforce-layout-dreamforce-2012)

But do you think we need to leave them be? I know AskUbuntu and other sites, close these as off-topic usually.

There might be some questions that can stay open, if they are very specific, or have merit, but on a general rule of thumb, what say you?

Answer (score 2):

Since there's actually some concrete evidence of what he's asking about, and the question is very specifically targeted ("is this UI here announced?") I'm not opposed to it at all. Salesforce releases and announces so many things keeping track of them all and what details are public is incredibly challenging.

Anything that doesn't have this same level of targeted question about the future should really be closed as overly broad ("what's coming in winter 14?").

So I'd say normal question rules apply: if it's broad or speculative it should be closed under existing rules.